# Python: Why printed it as blank from a list type by using for loop(edited: case solved)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm trying to extract data using web scraping with python. The information contains a table of content of the movie released dates and nations. After I requested and used BeautifulSoup. It printed out as a blank []. I don't know how to fix it... Here is my code:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response) 
    element_dates = ".ipl-zebra-list ipl-zebra-list--fixed-first release-dates-table-test-only" # css selector (date release table)
    select_datesTag = soup.select(element_dates)
    result = [i.text for i in select_datesTag]
    print(result)

    >>>[]
```

Edit:
Thank you all for trying to help me. As the previous printed result showed as blank, indicating that the information I tried to extract was unsuccessful.
The reason caused that was because of the false label I picked for the "element_dates" css selector, that instead of the ".ipl-..." but actually is ".release-date-item__date".

This is the link of the website I was working on and provided with the fixed line of codes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
target_url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/releaseinfo"
target_params = {"ref_": "tt_ov_inf"}
response = requests.get(target_url, params = target_params)
response = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
element_dates = ".release-date-item__date"
print(element_dates) # successfully printed all the data with element_dates variable.
```

Comment: Try printing some of the earlier variables, like `select_datesTag` to see if it is begin created correctly.

Comment: `select_datesTag` must be empty

Comment: [edit] your question, and include the actual `HTML` source instead of asking blindly. for a quick tip. don't use `spaces` within your CSS Selector, just replace it with `.` dot

Comment: You might try in your browser tools to test your css selector to see if it's correct:

    var stuff = document.querySelectorAll('.ipl-zebra-list ipl-zebra-list--fixed-first release-dates-table-test-only')

It looks to me like the selector might be wrong.